# behaviourSubject returns [object][object] when its subscribed

Tags: javascript, angular

Im working with a bank API for the payment.what banks want to response is he Ban Pay JavaScript will perform an HTTP redirect in the top frame to the completeUrl. what completeUrl the url i should give the bank api to send their response.in my app.component.ts

```
          this.http.post("BankEndURL",quote,).subscribe(s=>{
    //here i get quote 
      this.newpay=s;
      
      //here im passing the paymentID to my service in angular to store there,because 
            at the end of the transaction ,if its successful i need it to show the transaction data
            this.dataService.setData(s);
       //here i send a quote to backend to give me a bankurl with payment data
       this.http.post("SecondBakednURL",this.newpay).subscribe(s=>{
     
         this.payaddress= s['reDirectAuthorizationHref'];
         //here i open the url to redirect the user to the payment portal
          window.open(this.payaddress);
```

here is the service i have created :

```
public sharedData = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

constructor() {}

```
  getData(){   
  return this.sharedData;
       }

setData(data:any){
this.sharedData.next(data);
}
```

and here is my receiver component,the one which the bank will hit it once the transaction is successful,im going to show the transction data of the user

```
        constructor(private dataService:DataService) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataService.getData().pipe(
          filter(data => !!data)
        ).subscribe(data => {
          alert(data)
        });
```

but data here returns null

Comment: It's an instance of `BehaviorSubject` and when you use `alert()` it shows you the string representation of it like `[object object]`. You can use `console.log()` rather than `alert()` to get more details. If you want to get the data in the stream, you need to use `subscribe()` method of it, like you did in HTTP request.

Comment: i put  console.log("the object"+data); and i get there we go[object Object]

Comment: You are using `+` operator which also converts the object to a string. You can use `console.log('the object', data)`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz now it shows the object BehaviorSubject should i get the data from it?why it shows the BehaviorSubject ?and not the data inside

Comment: Because `getData()` returns the subject itself. You need to subscribe to it like `this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => { console.log(data)})`

Comment: it shows null now

Comment: It is because you initiate the subject with the value `null`. Unless you call `setData()` with a value, it will remain `null` and every new subscriber will get the latest value, which is `null`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz how should change it?what i should put there instead of null?

Comment: is the `post` to "url" hapenning ? if not then `setData` will not be called and your Subject will remain `null`

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez yes because i log it the(s) and there is data there

Comment: maybe uploading your code to an online platform so we can run it might help (the minimal code needed to replicate issue)

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez cant because its bank api,when i hit there api they send me back with a link for user to click and enter card detail and pay,if the payment is successful they will hit my http://localhost:4200/success-component ,there i need to show the amount is paid and customer detail,here is where i need the service we are talking about,its sending null,even though it contains data

Comment: I have posted an answer

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `getSharedData()` returns the behavior subject itself, so the sensible thing to do in this case is to subscribe to it in order to receive the data that you are emitting when calling `setData`.

In the receiver component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.getData().pipe(
    filter(data => !!data)
  ).subscribe(data => {
    alert(data)
  });
}
```

Comment: its shows null ,damn

Comment: then filter out the null values using the filter pipe operator. I edited the answer to include the filter logic

Comment: the alert does not fire,i think its because data is null

Comment: Ok, so the `this.http.post("url", quote)` call is not hitting the subscribe handler, that could be happening because of a http error. Open the browser console, go to the network tab and see if you can find the request in question. Maybe it actually returns null from the server.

Comment: thanks for your comments,i found them very useful and learned a lot,turned out since my  url gets hit from the bank,it will open a new tab and there was the issue,could not transfer data between two tabs,what i did was used local storage to sort the issue,stupid but seems working!